# pushViewController using uibutton to a UICollectionviewController Programatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

I want to push a UICollectionViewController when i press a uibutton. I have test some and when i press the button it navigates to a blank ViewController.

Root View Controller (CategoryViewController)

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //UIButton

    let image = UIImage(named: "menudo") as UIImage?
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CategoryViewController.action(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

func action(sender: UIButton!) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
    let collectionViewController = MealCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(collectionViewController, animated: true)

}
```

I want to show this ViewController when i press the uibutton (MealCollectionViewController)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class MealCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    //Creating the CellId for reusable cell

    private let cellId = "cellId"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        //Creating CollectionView

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        //setting the cellId reusable to show on screen USE CATEGORY CELL BECAUSE MEALCOLLECTION VIEW IS NOT A CELL

        collectionView?.registerClass(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }


    //Creating the layout for the cell 

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        return cell
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: r u using strotyborad , or xib

Comment: I am using a storyboard

Comment: Then try my code. on your button click method.

Comment: check whether your `numberOfItemsInSection ` `cellForItemAtIndexPath `  `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` methods getting called or not..

Answer (score 1):

If you are Using storyboard then use this code...

```
 let meal: MealCollectionViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("STORYBIARD_CONTROLLER_IDEBTIFIER_NAME"))! as! MealCollectionViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(meal, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code -

let mealController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your controller identifier name here") as MealCollectionViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mealController, animated: true)